# cocoonJS css not working

Tags: javascript, css, cocoonjs

I built a hello world app with a separate css file for the color of the background and size of a div and when I get my cocoonJS app it's all black.

Does CocoonJS support css/css3 or does it only support css3d?

For instance, being able to embed Bootstrap would be very useful.

Comment: Which environment are you using? canvas+ or webview+?

Comment: I tried both. But in general it should be able to load an external css file?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working demos list: https://cocoonjsservice.ludei.com/cocoonjslaunchersvr/demo-list/
It includes actually everything what cocoonjs can do.
What you need is the webView demo where you can see how they handle the external css file:
http://storage.cocoonjsservice.ludei.com/demos/cjs8336823350010472889Webview.zip
You can also simply install the cocoonjs launcher from the app store and click Demos to have a quick look what they actually do :)